# Send message WhatsApp with python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium

[I sent a WhatsApp message from Python, selenium. It opens WhatsApp Web and sends a message to it, and it appears within a second, but I open the chat, and the message does not reach the number that I entered in the code, and this error appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeUBz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe the problem could be a permission with your device (maybe turning it into developer mode could help), but I think that an easier option would be to use the library pywhatkit. It is an easier way to send Whatsapp messages with python and there are many online resources to help you learn how to use it.  https://pypi.org/project/pywhatkit/

Comment: My device in developer mode and this showed to me in terminal Get LATEST chromedriver version for 99.0.4844 google-chrome
Driver [C:\Users\ra8da\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\99.0.4844.51\chromedriver.exe] found in cache

Answer (score 0):

- try to install packages in anaconda
- Install Selenium using pip.
- Install the web driver for your browser.
- Launch the browser using Selenium.